# Shows the fatal: bad boolean config value 'true~' for 'http.sslverify' when i try git push -u origin main

Tags: git, github

[image: error message]

try to upload to GitHub account but face the same issue.

Comment: The error message is clear. What is your question? And do not show pictures of text.

Answer (score 1):

`git config --global http.sslverify true` should fix that - and make sure you don't have the tilde (`~`) on the end this time.